# String replacing does not work. Am I overlooking something?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying my best to build a generator for the fantastic WordPress Plugin Boilerplate by Tom Mc Farlin. All works out quite well. I load the file from github, extract it to a directory and replace all needed strings like 'plugin_name', 'Your name ' etc.

Unfortunately there is a protected class variable named $plugin_name and some other tiny bits. So I decided to 'repair' some flaws after replacing, like this:

```
// Repair some flaws
$repair_file = $newAbsDir.'/plugin-name/trunk/includes/class-'.$new_plugin_name.'.php';
$repair_file_content = file_get_contents($repair_file);
$repair_strings = array(
    '$'.$new_plugin_name => '$plugin_name', 
    '$this->'.$new_plugin_name => '$this->plugin_name', 
    'get_'.$new_plugin_name => 'get_plugin_name'
);
foreach($repair_strings as $string => $replace){
    $repair_file_content = str_replace($string, $replace, $repair_file_content);
}
file_put_contents($repair_file, $repair_file_content);
```

BUt what seemed to work quite well with my glob array of files, does simply not work with the above. I assume it has something to do with the dollar sign. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Absolutely unclear what are you trying to replace

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you going through all the files successfully? Are some things being changed? The wrong things? Is it writing the finished files properly? Have you checked that your `$repair_strings` array is being populated correctly? Have you tried replacing it with a fixed array to see if that works?

Comment: why the `foreach`? `str_replace` can handle arrays: `str_replace(array_keys($repairStrings), $repairStrings, $content);` saves the bother of looping through the array, and calling `str_replace` on the entire string over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If **search** and **replace** are arrays, then `str_replace()` takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on **subject**.

So, it's like [Elias Van Ootegem said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702498/string-replacing-does-not-work-am-i-overlooking-something#comment40175219_25702498), do a simple `str_replace()` without `foreach()`. The array values are passed on the literal array and the keys on [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). And as the array keys are the ones to be searched, you have to invert the array:

```
$repair_strings = array(
    '$plugin_name' => '$'.$new_plugin_name, 
    '$this->plugin_name' => '$this->'.$new_plugin_name, 
    'get_plugin_name' => 'get_'.$new_plugin_name
);
$repair_file_content = str_replace( array_keys( $repair_strings ), $repair_strings, $repair_file_content );
```

Inverting the array is just to keep the logic `search => replace`, but to use your original array it's a matter of:

```
$repair_file_content = str_replace( $repair_strings, array_keys( $repair_strings ), $repair_file_content );
```

Comment: Seems that I did not explain he problem well enough. I tried something simplified, that did not work either. Let's assume the following: I create a new plugin with the name "My fantastic plugin". During the cloning process I replace all occurencies of the string 'Plugin_Name' with the string "My_fantastic_plugin".

Unfortunately it replaces three parts that should not be replaced. So here's what I try to achieve:
I give the Variable $new_plugin_name = 'My_fantastic_plugin'. After that I look for the String '$My_fantastic_plugin' and would like to replace it with the string '$plugin_name_

Comment: I tried it like this:
`// Repair some flaws
$repair_file = $newAbsDir.'/plugin-name/trunk/includes/class-'.$new_plugin_name.'.php';
$repair_file_content = file_get_contents($repair_file);
$string_to_search_for = '$'.$new_plugin_name;
$string_to_replace_with = '$plugin_name';
$repair_file_content = str_replace($string_to_search_for, $string_to_replace_with, $repair_file_content);
file_put_contents($repair_file, $repair_file_content);
`
But the replacement simply doesn't take place :(

Answer (score 0):

**D'oh ...**

$My_fantastic_plugin differs slightly from $my_fantastic_plugin. Sorry for the hassle and thank you for the good advice with `$repair_file_content = str_replace( array_keys( $repair_strings ), $repair_strings, $repair_file_content );`